# Как правильно динамически изменять цвета у элементов recyclerview

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, mobile-development

Необходима ваша помощь. Есть адаптер для `RecyclerView`. В него приходит объект категории с некоторым содержимым, в том числе с полем, отвечающие за важность (в нем лежит 0 или 1). В зависимости от числа, я хотел бы изменять цвет layout. Изначально реализация была в методе bind.

```
      void bind(Category category) {
            nameCategory.setText(category.nameCategory);
            sumSpending.setText(String.valueOf(category.amountSpending));
            if (category.importance == 1) {
                nameCategoryBack.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_name_necessary_category);
                layoutCategoryBack.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorSecondaryDark);
            }
            this.category = category;
        }
```

Также я пробовал другую реализацию в методе `onBindViewHolder()`.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final viewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(sortedList.get(position), expenses);
        if (holder.category.importance == 1) {
            holder.nameCategoryBack.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_name_necessary_category);
            holder.layoutCategoryBack.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorSecondaryDark);
        }
    }
```

Все идет хорошо, но после того как количество созданных элементов превысило число, после которого происходит замена содержимого элементов в `RecyclerView`, начинается некорректное отображение цвета  layout, но содержимое остается верным. Как я могу правильно реализовать замену цветов фона layout?

Comment: Добавьте блок `else {}` и там задавайте дефолтные значения

Answer (score 2):

Как вы думаете, почему `RecyclerView` имеет такое название?

Вся его крутость заключается в переиспользовании элементов. `RecyclerView` реализует паттерн **ViewHolder**, суть которого заключается в том, что одновременно в памяти хранятся только те элементы которые помещаются на экране и несколько соседних.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вместо того чтоб постоянно вызывать метод `findViewById()` которой выполняется не очень быстро `RecyclerView` переиспользует те View которые больше не видны пользователю. И у нас появляется такое понятие как `DirtyView` - это `View` на которые уже не используются но на них хранится заданные параметры какого-то элемента.

И тут появляется прикол: если вы пишите в методе onBindViewHolder() какой-то `if` то в момент когда эта вьюшка переиспользуется она приходит в этот `if` и если `if` не `true` то она просто игнорирует биндинг этого поля. Таким образом там остается старое значение.

Отсюда следует правило: ***"Если в методе onBindViewHolder есть if то ВСЕГДА должен быть else"*** в противном случае у вас будут неверные параметры от старых биндингов.